# Why is my function not being recognized? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Okay, so I have heavily reduced the code, its a little different now, but it does the same thing.

game-socket.js

```
//Start Fight Action
socket.on("fight", () => {
 combat(io, socket, app);
});
```

action-timer.js

```
const combat = require("./combat/combat");
module.exports = (type, io, socket, app) => {
  if (type == "combat") {
    app.online.actionTime = setTimeout(() => {
      combat(io, socket, app);
    }, 1000);
  } else if (type == "tradeskill") {
  }
};
```

combat.js

```
const startAction = require("../action-timer");
module.exports = (io, socket, app) => {
  //Run another combat
  console.log("COMBAT");
  startAction("combat", io, socket, app);
};
```

Error:

```
action-timer.js:5
      combat(io, socket, app);
      ^

TypeError: combat is not a function
    at Timeout.app.online.actionTime.setTimeout [as _onTimeout] (C:\Users\wjpop\Desktop\kog\funcs\action-timer.js:5:7)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:327:15)
    at processTimers (timers.js:271:5)
```

Comment: Could you please add more detail about the error? You wrote "it will say the middle function, is not a function" and "The last file (combat) this is where the error hits.". Could you please specify the exact error message and the exact position in the js where the error occurs?

Comment: "*it will say the "middle" function, is not a function*" what is the "middle" function? Can you provide more details on what the error is and where exactly it occurs?

Comment: If possible, please create a small executable example which demonstrates the error. Remove as much code as you can while still getting the error.

Comment: I updated for the full error, and labeled the code based on their file name.

Comment: There, I have reduced the code as much as I can, producing the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, weird that I had to do this, as normally it doesn't need to be done like this but action-timer.js should be like so:

```
module.exports = (type, io, socket, app) => {
  const combat = require("./combat/combat");
  if (type == "combat") {
    app.online.actionTime = setTimeout(() => {
      combat(io, socket, app);
    }, 1000);
  } else if (type == "tradeskill") {
  }
};
```